# Apache 2.4 executes only some CGI scripts

Tags: browser

I'm using Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 in a VirtualBox VM. Things are *almost* working...

Some of my cgi scripts run/execute, but other scripts only display the source for the script. There are no errors or interesting entries in the access.log or error.log files.

> **Update:** After further troubleshooting, I believe the problem was browser caching (sigh!) After force reloading (Cmd-Shift-R on Mac),
>   they all execute as desired. (I believe the scripts that executed properly the
>   first time were those that I tested when I had the configuration
>   correct; the ones that simply listed their source were the ones I tested first.)
>
> For the record, the settings below *are* working correctly now.

All scripts end in .cgi, all invoke `#!/usr/bin/perl` as the first line, all have the same permissions (with +x). I have appended the ls of the "cgi" directory, and the site's config file.

What am I missing that would cause some files to execute, while others list? Many thanks!

CGI directory, with permissions:

```
wnr@wnr-VirtualBox:/usr/local/webview/www/flow$ ls -al *.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr 89720 Aug  9  2013 adhoc.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr 10535 Apr  2  2013 adhocClick.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr  6155 Mar 19  2012 adhocIf.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr   929 Feb 25  2013 configdump.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr 13325 Apr  8  2013 exporter.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr  6624 Mar 19  2012 flow-collector-stats.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr  2716 May  9 12:28 getFilter.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr   124 May  9 12:48 hirich.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr 88514 May  9 12:27 render.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wnr wnr  8242 Apr  1  2013 weblog.cgi
```

*Note: weblog.cgi and hirich.cgi both execute as expected, the others simply list the source code...*

Here's the site's config file:

```
wnr@wnr-VirtualBox:/usr/local/webview/www/flow$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

Alias "/webview" "/usr/local/webview/www"

<Directory "/usr/local/webview/www" >
#     Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
     Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
     Require all granted
     AllowOverride All
     SetEnv no-gzip 1
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>

# <Directory "/usr/local/webview/www/flow" >
#     Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
#     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
# </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can execute the scripts directly on the shell, like so:

$ ./script.cgi

Your shebang might contain a trailing \r, a common trick is to replace #!/usr/bin/perl with #!/usr/bin/perl -w

Comment: If the problem really were due to `*.cgi` files being created on Windows with CRLF line endings, and copied over to the server, the scripts would not be displayed as text. Instead, Apache would fail to run them, would send 500 to the browser, and there would be a message in the error log.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. That turned out not to be the problem - see original post for an update.

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** After further troubleshooting, I believe the problem was browser caching (sigh!) After force reloading (Cmd-Shift-R on Mac), they all execute as desired.

This explains why some of the scripts executed, and some didn't, even though they all had the same permissions and were in the same directory.

I believe the scripts that executed properly the first time were those that I tested when I had the configuration correct; the ones that simply listed their source were the ones I tested first.

For the record, the settings above are working correctly now.

And always remember: if your browser isn't showing what you expect, Force Reload.

Comment: Instead of posting this comment as an answer, consider deleting your question. It should be closed as off-topic anyhow due to: "*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*"

Comment: Thanks for this note: it's a good observation. However, I am going to disagree with you. The problem is reproducible (under fairly simple conditions) and was caused not by a typographical error, but by a failure of my troubleshooting process. Furthermore, the existing example (the shortest reproducible test case) is scrupulously correct. So I want to leave this as a reminder that external causes (browser caching) can cause strictly correct code to appear to misbehave.